# How can I add the language prefix to all router links in my components without injecting the service?

Tags: angular

I have a service that stores the current language in a variable or observable. Within my application, I create components that require routerLink to navigate to other pages. To each link, I must append the current language dynamically to the URL, as the language may change, affecting the value of the variable in the service.

Unfortunately, since my components are designed as "dumb components," they lack awareness of the language service, leading to reduced reusability. As a result, I need to inject this service into each of my components like this: `<a routerLink="service.lang + '/path/to'">`.

I'm looking for a way to add the language prefix in one central location in the code, rather than having to include it in every individual component. Is there a method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a resolver on the top level of your routes:

```
// language-resolver.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LanguageService } from './language.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LanguageResolver implements Resolve<string> {
  constructor(private languageService: LanguageService) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): string | Observable<string> | Promise<string> {
    const currentLanguage = this.languageService.getCurrentLanguage();
    return currentLanguage;
  }
}
```

And use it on the router at the top level.

```
// app-routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LanguageResolver } from './language-resolver.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':lang', // The route parameter for the language code
    resolve: {
      lang: LanguageResolver // Use the LanguageResolver to fetch the current language
    },
    children: [
      // Your other routes go here for this language
      // For example: { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
    ]
  },
  // Other routes without language parameter can go here
  // For example: { path: '', redirectTo: '/en', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```